# MS Project - Baseline Work shows in accurate values when extracting using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

***Updated 20Nov23: I am adding line of code.***

Apologies for not coming back earlier but I got pulled into some other stuff. I have multiple Tsvs and they are set as follows:

Set tsvs = Tsk.TimeScaleData(Tsk.Start, Tsk.Finish, pjTaskTimescaledCost, pjTimescaleMonths)
Set tsvs1 = Tsk.TimeScaleData(Tsk.Start, Tsk.Finish, pjTaskTimescaledWork, pjTimescaleMonths)
Set tsvs2 = Tsk.TimeScaleData(Tsk.Start, Tsk.Finish, pjTaskTimescaledBaselineWork, pjTimescaleMonths)

For Each tsv In tsvs

```
xlRange.Value = Tsk.UniqueID
xlRange.Offset(0, 1) = Tsk.Id
xlRange.Offset(0, 2) = Tsk.Name
xlRange.Offset(0, 3) = Tsk.GetField(FieldNameToFieldConstant("Project")) 'Project name
xlRange.Offset(0, 4) = Tsk.Duration / 480 'duration in days                               
xlRange.Offset(0, 6) = tsv.StartDate    ' Period
xlRange.Offset(0, 5) = tsv.Value        ' Planned Cost ($)

'Calculate Planned Work (hrs) for time phased data
If tsvs1.Item(tsv.Index).Value = "" Then
   xlRange.Offset(0, 6) = 0 
Else
   xlRange.Offset(0, 6) = (tsvs1.Item(tsv.Index).Value) / 60 ' Planned Work (hrs)
End If

'Calculate Baseline Work (hrs) for time phased data
If tsvs2.Item(tsv.Index).Value = "" Then
   xlRange.Offset(0, 7) = 0
Else
   xlRange.Offset(0, 7) = (tsvs2.Item(tsv.Index).Value) / 60 ' Baseline Work (hrs)
End If
```

I have a simple project consist of 5 tasks. All the tasks are fixed work. Each task is assigned 76 hrs and a duration of 10 days. Baseline was saved before modifying the duration of task2 to 20 days. When extracting data after modification, it changes the baseline work.I have attached an image here.[image: Baseline shows incorrect data]

***Original Post:***

Background:
I have been using VBA scripts to extract the baseline work as timephased data on monthly timescale. The scripts shows correct values once I have set the baseline. After baselining, I have to change start dates of few activities due to a delay event. I didn't modify the baseline as it is used to track and compare the project progress.

Problem:
After adding the delay event, I extracted the baseline work as timephased data but it is showing me less hrs from the date where delay event is addded. I have no clue why it is doing this. Any help is appreciated.

I have already confirmed that there are no changes in Task usage view & Resource usage view in MS Project but somehow it is reducing baseline work(hrs) when extracting timephased data. Also to note that the planned work is coming accurate.

Comment: Whereas this part of the forum is for programming issues you need to show us what you have tried (i.e. post your code).

Comment: When using the TimeScaleData method, be sure to use the appropriate StartDate and EndDate (e.g. use BaselineStart and BaselineFinish). Please edit your post to include code and screen shots of your schedule. It can be helpful to add Baseline Work to the Details in the Task Usage view and see how it compares to what you expect.

Comment: @RachelHettinger, my tsvs picks up Start and Finish dates. I have been extracting both task assignments and resource assignments. I have set five tsvs that are uses to pick up cost, work, actual work, remaining work and baseline work. I wonder if I change to baselinestart and baseline finish in my tsvs, it will have the same effect on planned work. Anyway, I have to try when I get back to work. I will update here. Many thanks